# Advantages of XOAUTH2 in nodemailer

Tags: node.js, oauth, nodemailer

The [nodemailer](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer) module (allows to send emails in a node.js app) supports XOAUTH2 authentication against Gmail accounts. Why would one want to use this for general purpose email notifications as opposed to just specifying the `user:` and `pass:` parameters in `auth`? I understand that the password is then stored in plain text, but it's never propagated anywhere. Also, the XOAUTH2 method seems to require a `clientSecret:` parameter, which should also probably not be made public. So what are the advantages here?

Similar question: how can I include authentication information in the app without pushing it into the remote repo? Is there a way to just ignore those lines with Git?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using XOAUTH is useful when you want to send e-mails on behalf of your users (eg. as if the sender would be the user, not your application) - instead of asking their passwords, you can ask them to authorize your application through the OAuth mechanism. The resulting client secrets are known only to you, valid only for accessing the e-mail of the user, nothing more and the user can revoke these client tokens any time they wish.

If you do not want to send mail on behalf your users but with your own credentials, then there is no point of using XOAUTH.

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot. Any ideas about the second part of the question? How do I "hide" the authentication credentials from the public code (on GitHub) while keeping them in the local and production environment?

Comment: Use environment variables to hide sensitive data. For example set environment variable CLIENT_SECRET in your server and then use it as `process.env.CLIENT_SECRET` in your code

Comment: Saved me time trying to get XOauth2 to work, thanks!